# to build iOS apps from command line with different info.plist files

Tags: ios, objective-c, command-line

I want to build my iOS app from command line along with parameters that i can give to use the appropriate `info.plist` file. Can this thing be established? ie. giving different `info.plist` files for creating two different app packages for the same project and that too from command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create two (or more) targets in your project: target1, target2.

Create two plists in your project, but assign different target membership for them.

In command line:

```
xcodebuild -project projectname -target target1
xcodebuild -project projectname -target target2
```

This will build the same project but with different plists.

Here is a reference for xcodebuild's command line: [xcodebuild](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html).

References for targets: [Xcode Target](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Targets.html).

Comment: so are u telling target1 is info1.plist and target2 is info2.plist?

Comment: You can have plists with the same name, but you should put them into different folders: target1/Info.plist, target2/Info.plist. Or you can have plists with different names. You specify which plist is used in target settings.

Comment: and can u tell me the absolute path of target1 or target2?

Comment: These are not folders but targets. They have no absolute or relative path. Each Xcode project consists of one, two or more targets.

Comment: I've added a link to learn about targets: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Targets.html